# update product inventory in magento using magento soap api in C#

Tags: c#, magento, soap

I am trying to update the Product inventory in Magento, using Magento SOAP API in C#.
When I call the product_stock.update api, it returns true. But when I check in Magento Admin panel, it is not updated.

```
ProductInventoryStock[] arrProdInventoryStock = new ProductInventoryStock[1];
for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt < arrProdInventoryStock.Count(); iCnt++)
{
  ProductInventoryStock objProdInventoryStock = new ProductInventoryStock();
  objProdInventoryStock.qty = "111";
  objProdInventoryStock.is_in_stock = 1;
  objProdInventoryStock.manage_stock = 1;
  objProdInventoryStock.use_config_manage_stock = 0;
  arrProdInventoryStock[iCnt] = objProdInventoryStock;
}

bool test = Inventory.Update(apiUrl, sessionId, new object[] { "126", arrProdInventoryStock });
```

Please check this, and is there any problem over here. or something else?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Im using `Mangento 1.9.x` with the `v2_soap?wsdl=1` and integrate with C# (4.5 Framework), I made a simple function that will update the stock, taking parameters as `activeSession`, `ProductId`, `stockQty`, `stockStatus`. Most important thing to note is that I've set the value to `is_in_stock` along with `is_in_stockSpecified`

```
        protected void AddInventory(string activeSession, string ProductId, string stockQty, int stockStatus)
        {
        MagentoService mservice = new MagentoService();
        catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity uStock = new catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity();
        int stock_status=stockStatus;            
        uStock.qty = stockQty;
        uStock.is_in_stock = stock_status;
        uStock.is_in_stockSpecified = Convert.ToBoolean(stock_status);
        int result;

        try
        {                
            result = mservice.catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate(activeSession, ProductId, uStock);                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {         
        }            
        }
```